# Creating a new VSTO crashes Outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto

A bit of a strange one.

I'm learning how to create VSTO add ins for Outlook and I've barely done much and what I seem to have already done, causes Outlook to disable it as it takes too long to load. (Says it takes 1.57 seconds)

All I've literally done is:

1. Created a new Project for Outlook 2013 and 2016 VSTO
2. Added the ribbon add in by going to Project -> Add New Item
3. Set the Ribbon type to Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer
4. Added a button
5. Press F5 to test

I'm more concerned that if I was to develop, will this VSTO take longer to generate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit the F5 button on the keyboard the add-in is run under the debugger with non-optimized code. I'd suggest testing the RELEASE configuration of your add-in instead. In that case you will get an optimized assembly without debug symbols defined, so it should be run a lot faster.

The [New in Outlook for developers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj228679.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) page states the following:

> Extending the add-in resiliency pillar of Outlook 2010, Outlook 2013 monitors add-in performance metrics such as add-in startup, shutdown, folder switch, item open, and invoke frequency. Outlook records the elapsed time in milliseconds for each performance monitoring metric.
>
> For example, the startup metric measures the time required by each connected add-in during Outlook startup. Outlook then computes the median startup time over 5 successive iterations. If the median startup time exceeds 1000 milliseconds (1 second), then Outlook disables the add-in and displays a notification to the user that an add-in has been disabled. The user has the option of always enabling the add-in, in which case Outlook will not disable the add-in even if the add-in exceeds the 1000 millisecond performance threshold